# Extract Specific Set of data from a String in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have the string '**1_A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5**' and I am trying to extract the data '**A_B_C_D_E**'. I am trying to remove the **_1_2_3_4_5** & the **1_** portion from the string. Which is essentially the numeric portion in the string. any special characters after the last alphabet must also be removed. In this example the **_** after the character **E** must also not be present.

and the Query I am trying is as below

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('1_A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5','[^0-9]+',1,1) 
from dual
```

The Data I get from the above query is as below: -

```
_A_B_C_D_E_
```

I am trying to figure a way to remove the underscore towards the end. Any other way to approach this?

Comment: Please state more specifically what you must keep and what you must remove from the string. Is the part you must keep always at the beginning, or can it also be in the middle? Is the pattern letter-underscore-letter-underscore (etc) and then same with digits, and you must just keep the letters part? Or what? Don't ask us to guess!

Comment: So, are the "letters" always first and the "digits" always last?

Comment: You must clarify your question with some sample strings with varying combinations of string available in you data and the expected output for each. It is hard to assume things while answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "letters" come first and then the "digits", you could do something like this:

```
select regexp_substr('A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5','.*[A-Z]') from dual;
```

This will pull all the characters from the beginning of the string, up to the last upper-case letter in the string (`.*` is greedy, it will extend as far as possible while still allowing for one more upper-case letter to complete the match).

Comment: `select regexp_substr('1_A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5','.*[A-Z]') from dual;` returns `1_A_B_C_D_E` which is not good. I voted up your answer as it works perfectly on the string used in the question.

Comment: @cdaiga  - see my comments under the original question. I asked the OP for clarification, he amended the question but it is still not clear. In my answer above, read the first sentence - I stated my assumption explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the string '1_A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5' and I am trying to extract the data 'A_B_C_D_E'

Use **REGEXP_REPLACE**:

```
SQL> SELECT trim(BOTH '_' FROM
  2         (REGEXP_SUBSTR('1_A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5','[0-9]+', ''))) str
  3  FROM dual;

STR
---------
A_B_C_D_E
```

How it works:

1. `REGEXP_REPLACE` will replace all numeric occurrences **'[0-9]+'** from the string. Alternatively, you could also use POSIX character class **'[^[:digit:]]+'**
2. `TRIM BOTH '_'` will remove any leading and lagging `_` from the string.

Also using **REGEXP_SUBSTR**:

```
SELECT trim(BOTH '_' FROM 
       (REGEXP_SUBSTR('1_A_B_C_D_E_1_2_3_4_5','[^0-9]+'))) str 
FROM dual;
STR
---------
A_B_C_D_E
```